# After DOM Modification using .find() to get Form still enzyme test is failing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I am new to enzyme testing in "React" and need to modify a test case due to change in dom.

**Case 1:**

```
return (
    <RForm className={classes} schema={schema} uiSchema={uiSchema} >
      {children}
    </RForm>
);
```

Test Case:

```
  it('should call change handler Form component', () => {
    const data = { formData: { id: 'someId' } };
    const expectedSate = Object.assign({}, data, { dirtyFields: ['id'] });
    const wrapper = shallow(<Form schema={formSchema} />);
    wrapper.simulate('change', data);
    expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual(expectedSate);
  });
```

This runs fine .... !

**Case 2:**

```
return (
  <div className="form-wrapper">
    {isLoading ? <MyLoader /> : null}
    <RForm className={classes} schema={schema} uiSchema={uiSchema} >
      {children}
    </RForm>
  </div>
);
```

Test Case:

```
  it('should call change handler Form component', () => {
    const data = { formData: { id: 'someId' } };
    const expectedSate = Object.assign({}, data, { dirtyFields: ['id'] });
    const wrapper = shallow('.form-wrapper').find(<Form schema={formSchema} />);
    wrapper.simulate('change', data);
    expect(wrapper.state()).toEqual(expectedSate);
  });
```

This is failing ... (I tried use .find to find my form and assign it to wrapper here ... but think this is giving error)

Please, can someone help?